In which fields with characteristic $0$ does there exist a pair of roots of unity, distinct from $\{-1,1\}$, that differ by $2$?
I am investigating the existence of pairs of roots of unity in a field $k$ of characteristic $0$, distinct from $\{-1,1\}$, that differ by $2$. This problem arises from a functional equation related to non-zero polynomials over a field.
Consider the functional equation:
$$
f(x^2) = f(x) f(x+2)
$$
where $f(x)$ is a non-zero polynomial defined over a field $k$ with characteristic $0$. To facilitate the analysis, it is natural to work within the algebraic closure $k^a$ of $k$.
Analysis:
For any root $c$ of such a polynomial $f$, both $c^2$ and $(c-2)^2$ must also be roots of $f$. This imposes strong constraints on the possible values of $c$, suggesting that $c$ and $c-2$ must be roots of unity.
Special Case for $k = \mathbb{C}$:
When the field $k$ is the complex numbers $\mathbb{C}$, the situation simplifies. Every root of $f$ must be $1$. In this case, the functional equation admits the solution:
$$
f(x) = (x - 1)^d
$$
for any degree $d$.
General Question:
In more general fields $k$ with characteristic $0$, I am interested in identifying fields where there exist roots of unity distinct from $\{-1,1\}$, say $c$ and $c-2$, such that the difference between the two roots is exactly $2$.
Does this situation occur in other fields besides $\mathbb{C}$, and how does the field's structure affect the possibility of such pairs existing? Specifically, under what conditions on $k$ does this polynomial equation have non-trivial solutions?

There are no fields of characteristic zero with such elements.
Suppose, $c$ and $c-2$ are roots of unity in a field $k$ of characteristic zero. In particular, $c$ is algebraic, so we can choose an embedding $\mathbf Q[c] \hookrightarrow \bar{\mathbf Q} \subset \mathbf C$. Under this map, $c$ and $c-2$ both map to roots of unity again, so the problem reduces to the case $k = \mathbf C$.
In $\mathbf C$ write $c - 1 = x + y\mathrm i$ with $x,y \in \mathbf R$. As roots of unity have absolute value $1$, we get $(x+1)^2 + y^2 = 1$ and $(x-1)^2 + y^2 = 1$. The difference of both equations yields $x = 0$, plugging this into either equation gives $y = 0$. Thus, $c = 1$ and $c - 2 = -1$.
